# How to set a Date object from a timepicker?

Tags: android

I know i can store both date and time in a Date Object, altough i'm having troubles declaring a Date type object, all i need is the hours and minutes, normally i'd use .getTime() method if i needed to get a date from a datePicker, but with timePicker the app crashes, does anyone know what to do here?

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            Date date = calendar.getTime(); // What to do here?
            AddOcorrenciaActivity.horaChegada = date;
            Toast.makeText(AddOcorrenciaActivity.this, "You selected: " + formatHourMinute.format(AddOcorrenciaActivity.dataOcorrencia),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: All you want are the Hour and Minutes from the time picker? Why are you using a `Calendar` object? What format do you need as a result?

Comment: What is the error stack you get when the app crashes?

Comment: @Barns52 "HH:mm a", i already solved it though... i used the formatHourMinute on another Date object that was ment for another thing. The problem was that i was using some method on a null reference... which i see it why now